# Passing Variable into KML Generation with Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, kml

I am trying to pass in variables to a KML generator in a variety of ways based on the source within the code.  I have most of it working as expected, but when I try to pass in an array of data, there is nothing coming from that particular source.  Here is an example of my syntax:

```
function GenerateKML($Name, $Var1, $Var2) {
    $csvfiles = Get-ChildItem $global:directoryPath -include Name_*.csv -Recurse

$kml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
  <name>Test01</name>
$(
foreach ($csv in $csvfiles) {
  $rName = $csv.Name.Split("_")[1]
'
  <Folder>
    <name>{0}</name>' -f $rName
    $(
    for ($i = 2; $i -lt $Name.Count; $i++) {
      if ($Name[$i] -like $rName + "*") {
        rVar1 = $Var1[$i]
        rVar2 = $Var2 [$i]
      }
    }
    Import-Csv $csv | 
    foreach {
'
    <Placemark>
      <name>{0} - {1}</name>
      <TimeStamp>
        <when>{5}</when>
      </TimeStamp>
      <description>Utilization - {4}%</description>
      <styleUrl>#{5}</styleUrl>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>{2},{3}</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>' -f $_.Name, $_.Timestamp, $rVar1, $rVar2, $_.Utilization, $($_.Timestamp -replace '^(.*)(\d\d)(.*)$','${1}00$3')
    }
    )
'
  </Folder>'
}
)
</Document>
</kml>
"@

$kml | Out-File -Force -Encoding ascii ("Test.kml")
```

Based on this example code, you can the for loop where I am trying to iterate through the Name array, finding a match for the CSV file name.  Then once I find a match, I set up 2 variables:

> rVar1 and rVar2

I use these to pass into the KML generation.  This is the part that is not working as intended.  The rest works perfectly fine and I end up with a dynamic KML file that is populated as expected.  I feel like I am close, but I am missing a particular syntax to ensure the variables or arrays are read into the function properly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as expected.  The issue was that the variables were being manipulated before being passed into the new function (KML).  The original programmer was repeating variable names and ended up replacing a global array with a single variable for console output.  Once I traced that back, I was able to verify that the variable and array that I needed was being passed through the entire function properly.  What I have above for syntax is actually correct (aside from the small typo of placing $'s in front of the rVar1 and rVar2 instantiation.